# Separate market and limit orders from market depth/tick data

Tags: finance, python, machine-learning, financial-markets

From the website https://www.algoseek.com/equities/, we can get a sample of the full depth market/tick data. From the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03870.pdf page 8, I would like to extract the market orders and limit orders separately with timestamp of 1 second . Is it possible to do such a thing? If so, how?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a programming question.

Comment: @Helin This is not programming question. I asked theorically how to do it.

Comment: You've asked basically the same question 4 times, voting to close

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a programming question, or a data request question, or the same question thats been asked by the same user lots more times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. download the [data](https://www.algoseek.com/static/files/sample_data/equity_and_etf_etn/IBM.FullDepth.20140128.csv.zip)
2. open [Jupyter Notebook](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('IBM.FullDepth.20140128.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Timestamp']])

data['EventType'].unique()
```

> array(['ADD BID', 'ADD ASK', 'DELETE ASK', 'DELETE BID', 'TRADE ASK',
>          'EXECUTE BID', 'FILL BID', 'TRADE BID', 'FILL ASK', 'EXECUTE ASK',
>          'CROSS', 'CANCEL ASK', 'CANCEL BID'], dtype=object)

```
grouped = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date_Timestamp', freq='1s'))
groups = grouped.groups
keys = list(groups.keys())

df=grouped.get_group(keys[0])
df[df.EventType=='ADD BID']
```

[image]