# Market, Limit and Cancellation orders

Tags: finance, machine-learning, financial-markets

From the paper https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande448/2017/Final/Reports/gr4.pdf page 8, I need at least the limit and market order. I can easily find the full depth from dxfeed or algoseek, but I can't really separate clearly the market and limit orders for deep learning purposes. I thought to collect my own data, but the problem is I need the data right now. I don't have the choice to buy the data from a provider.

[image]

Any thoughts how to get the market and limit orders separately (intraday)?

Comment: Could you tell what dataset do you have right now? Is it orderbook or last transactions? And could you provide a quotation that you are talking about (at page 8).

Comment: I have the full depth/tick data so far. I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/41173

```
sell market orders: 'FILL ASK' (execute outstanding order in full), 'EXECUTE ASK' (execute outstanding order in part), 'TRADE ASK' (execute non-displayed order)
buy market orders: 'FILL BID', 'EXECUTE BID', 'TRADE BID'
bid order cancellation: 'DELETE BID' (delete outstanding order in full), 'CANCEL BID' (cancel outstanding order in part)
ask order cancellation: 'DELETE ASK', 'CANCEL ASK'
bid orders: 'ADD BID'
ask orders: 'ADD ASK'
```

Information from the documentation:
https://www.algoseek.com/static/files/documentation/equity_and_etf_etn/AlgoSeek.US.Equities.FullDepth.1.0.pdf